# Compile time error when adding generic object to collection of generics

Tags: c#, generics

we've reached a point where we have no clue how to continue:

SHORT:
We have a generic interface and a collection of the generic interface. Trying to add an implementation of the generic interface to the collection fails. What happens is that I get a compile time exception saying:

> cannot convert from TestApp.IState<T>' to TestApp.IState<TestApp.IView>'

LONG [Code example]:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var coll = new StateCollection();
        var state = new SomeState();
        coll.AddState(state);
    }
}

public class StateCollection
{
    private List<StateBase<IView>> _states = new List<StateBase<IView>>();

    public void AddState<T>(StateBase<T> state) where T: IView
    {
        _states.Add(state);
    }
}

public class SomeState : StateBase<SomeView>
{

    public IView View
    {
        get;
    }
}

public class SomeView : IView
{
}

public abstract class StateBase<T> where T : IView
{
    private SomeView _view;
    public SomeView View
    {
        get { return _view; }
    }
}

public interface IView
{
}
```

Why does this happen? In the AddState we mention that T has to be an instance of IState. Could someone help us out with why this happens and how to do what we want to do?

EDIT1:
We also tried:

```
    public void AddState(IState<IView> state)
    {
        _states.Add(state);
    }
```

But that just moves the compile time error to 'coll.AddState(state)'
So the same thing happens in another place.

EDIT2:
PROBLEM! I didn't give the right example. Out IState is not an interface but an abstract class. Very sorry for that! Changed code to use abstract class

Comment: What version of C# are you using? C# < 3.0 doesn't have variance with generics.

Comment: This is because `IState<SomeView>` is not `IState<IView>>`

Comment: _states is defined as <IState<Iview>> but your trying to add IState into that collection.

Comment: @sll SomeView does implement IView

Comment: @Oded I'm using .NET version 4.0

Comment: Templating and generics are great when you want to be able to re-use a single function with multiple types.  When you mix in inheritance and parent classes, it gets a little more interesting, and doesn't always work the way you think it would.  In this case, it doesn't look like you need the templating because you have the inheritance...

Comment: @Nevyn Can you explain why you think having inheritance removes the need for templating?

Comment: In my own code, we use a combination of both of these things.  We have a BaseObject and all the classes in the code implement it.  I dont need to template any of my generic usage functions (like lists or clones) because all the parameters ARE the base obj.  Templating is more useful when you need a function that uses something OTHER than the base object/interface.

Comment: @Nevyn I don't think that works for us. We need to have an overview of all our states. Every implementation of a state should have it's own view, which will be specific to that state. So SomeState will have SomeView, FooState will have FooView and BarState will have BarView

Comment: The posted code does not really compile (complains about unimplemented properties and such). I guess the edit broke it. Please try to make it representative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks more like a parameter error for the Add function.  Have you tried declaring the add function without using the generics?  The inheritance itself should allow it.  Make the AddState function look like like so:

**Edit (as per Edit2):**

As mentioned, the inheritance itself should take care of the generics.  As long as whatever class you declared properly implements `IView`, or `IState<IView>`, then there shouldn't be any issues...

```
public absract class StateBase
{
    public IView view { get; set; }

    ....
}

public Interface IView
{ ... }

public class StateCollection
{
    private List<StateBase> _states = new List<StateBase>();

    public void AddState(StateBase state)
    {
        _states.Add(state);
    }
}

public class SomeView : IView
{ ... }
```

etc etc and so on, as often as needed

```
public class SomeState : StateBase
{
    private SomeView my_view;

    public IView view
    {
        get { return (IView)SomeView; }
        set { ; }
    }
}

//program remains unchanged
```

In this case, SomeState is still an IState object, and all IState objects implement IView, and SomeView is an IView object.  SomeState implements SomeView internally.  Looks the same to me, but I dont know how well the adaption would work with your real code.

Any other classes would follow the same model.  The State will implement StateBase, and internally declare a custom View, which itself needs to extend IView.  That way the IView cast on the custom view will work.

**From comment:**

```
public class BarState : StateBase
{
    private BarView my_view;

    public IView view
    {
        get { return (IView)BarView; }
        set { ; }
    }
}

public class BarView : IView
{ ... }
```

Comment: I was editing the post at the same time you posted this issue. This also doesn't work. When I do this I just get "The best overloaded method match for 'TestApp.StateCollection.AddState(TestApp.IState<TestApp.IView>)' has some invalid arguments" when calling AddState (see EDIT1)

Comment: I tried state as IState<IView> but that just returns null as in, the casting fails

Comment: if the casting fails, then that means that the code doesn't recognize SomeState as a proper instance of IState<IView>, otherwise you would be able to cast it.  This seems to be the root of the issue, inheritance isn't working as it looks like it should with Templating.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the problem, but why and how do we get around this?

Comment: The real question I have at the moment: Would removing the templating break any other existing code, as long as the assumption that IView and StateBase and their relationship remains intact?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22984/discussion-between-mrsoundless-and-nevyn)

Comment: I've picked this answer because this is pretty much what we decided to use. We needed the specific IView in the StateBase because we had to use the type in another generic in the StateBase constructor, but we moved this code to the implementation of StateBase. Everything looks fine now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

**First solution**

```
public class StateCollection
    {
        private readonly List<IState<IView>> _states = new List<IState<IView>>();

        public void AddState(IState<IView> state)
        {
            _states.Add(state);
        }
    }
```

as suggested by Nevyn.
To have it to work, mark `T` as covariant in `interface IState<T>`

```
public interface IState<out T> where T:IView
    {
        IView View { get; }
    }
```

**Second solution** : (keep change in class `StateCollection`)

change interface `IState<T>` to

```
public interface IState<out T> where T : IView
    {
        T View { get; }
    }
```

and class SomeState to

```
public class SomeState : IState<SomeView>
    {
        public SomeView View{ get;private set; }
    }
```

**Solution for Edit2 :**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var coll = new StateCollection();
            var state = new SomeState();
            coll.AddState(state);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class StateCollection
    {
        private List<IStateBase<IView>> _states = new List<IStateBase<IView>>();

        public void AddState(IStateBase<IView> state)
        {
            _states.Add(state);
        }
    }

    public class SomeState : StateBase<SomeView>
    {
    }

    public class SomeView : IView
    {
    }

    public interface IStateBase<out T> where T : IView
    {
        T View { get; }
    }

    public abstract class StateBase<T> : IStateBase<T> where T : IView
    {
        public T View { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IView
    {
    }
```

Comment: @MrSoundless then... indeed, it won't work, as you can't use covariance outside interfaces and delegates.

Comment: @MrSoundless well see "Solution for Edit2" for a solution, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

How about these changes:

```
public class SomeState : IState<SomeView>
{
    public SomeView View
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Instead of using generic Type T use IView in AddState method

```
public void AddState(IState<IView> state)
{
    _states.Add(state);
}
```

Make T covariant in IState using `out` keyword

```
public interface IState<out T> where T : IView
{
    T View { get; }
}
```

### SOLUTION FOR EDIT2:

Don't know if it is ok for you but you can.

```
public class StateCollection
{
    private List<IState<IView>> _states = new List<IState<IView>>();

    public void AddState(IState<IView> state)
    {
        _states.Add(state);
    }
}

public class SomeState : StateBase<SomeView>
{
    public override SomeView View
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}

public abstract class StateBase<T> : IState<T> where T : IView
{
   public abstract T View { get; }
}

public interface IState<out T> where T : IView
{
    T View { get; }
}
```

Comment: What you are asking for is [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) which is only applicaple for interfaces and delegates. The only chance is extracting your abstract class to an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Add interface `IState` (non-generic) and inherit it from `IState<T>`. Then declare `_states` as `List<IState>` and method `AddState(IState state)`

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT: you just need to have your StateBase inherit from the covariant interface. You can't make a class directly covariant, you always have to go through an interface)

Try this:

```
public class StateCollection
{
    private List<IState<IView>> _states = new List<IState<IView>>();

    public void AddState(IState<IView> state)   
    {
        _states.Add(state);
    }
}

public class SomeState : StateBase<SomeView>
{
}

public class SomeView : IView
{
}

public interface IState<out T> where T : IView // now covariant with T
{
    T View { get; }
}

public abstract class StateBase<T> : IState<T> where T : IView
{
    public T View { get; set; }
}

public interface IView
{
}
```

Comment: @MrSoundless see edit to answer. If you can change the definition for your abstract class (adding inheritance from a covariant interface) you can still make it work