# C# Generic Class Type parameter (cannot implicitly convert)

Tags: c#, generics, types, parameters, implicit-conversion

**Scenario:**

```
class A { }

class B : A { }

class C<T> where T: A { }
```

**Question**

Why cant `C<A> = C<B>` when B is a subclass of A?
it throws the "cannot implicitly convert" error

Thanks

**--UPDATE--**
can i create an implicit method for that `C<A>` would recognize `C<B>`?

Comment: Please reread your question. What means _"Why cant C = C "_ ? Provide a compiling code snippet which enables  us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: What do you mean with C = C ?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674715/net-casting-generic-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133356/why-does-this-generic-cast-fail/1133389. The keywords you are looking for are covariance and contravariance :)

Comment: sorry forgot to add code blocks

Comment: You don't need those parenthesis for a start: `class C<T> where T: A { }`

Comment: [Bit of a long read but your answer is in here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) It has to do with C# not supporting covariance for generics.

Comment: you might also find some information over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14621564/238902)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [co-variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) if you need to do this, and because *co-variant* just work only with *interface and delegate*, so define an interface with the magic word [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) instead of class:

```
interface IC<out T> where T : A
{
}
```

So, you can assign like you want:

```
class CA : IC<A>
{}

class CB : IC<B>
{ }

IC<A> x = new CA();
IC<B> y = new CB();

x = y;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is Covariance and Contravariance in Generics which is only applicaple for interfaces and delegates. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402641/compile-time-error-when-adding-generic-object-to-collection-of-generics/14402975)

You can do the following in Framework >= 4:

```
interface IC<out T> where T : A

class C<T> : IC<T>  where T : A

IC<A> ica = new C<B>();
```

For your case you should extract an interface for `class C`

Answer (score 0):

`Why cant C<A> = C<B> when B is a subclass of A?` `B` is subclass of `A`, but `C<B>` not a subclass of `C<A>`. There is no assignment compatibility between  `C<B>` and `C<A>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `C<A>` is not `C<B>`

The thing is; if you could do

```
C<A> myA = new C<B>();
myA.Add(new A());
```

You'd have a problem, since `B is A`, but not `A is B`